# attendance system CHECK-IN & CHECK-OUT values in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL table where I have employee logs and the states of the log state 255 being (check-in) and state 1 being checked-out

I want to have the minimum check-in time and the max checkout time of each day date as a result.

This is the table that I have.
[image]

This is the Query
[image]

```
select [full name],
(SELECT MIN(time) AS CHECKIN FROM attendance WHERE state = 255 and fingerprint = id) checkin,
(SELECT MAX(time) AS CHECKIN FROM attendance WHERE state = 1 and fingerprint = id) checkout,
cast (date as date)
FROM employee full outer join attendance on fingerprint = id
group by id,fingerprint,[full name],date
```

The problem is that it selects the minimum and Max time but not by date

it basically searches the min and max times across all dates instead of each day as its own

notice how it gave the checkin (2:00) and checkout(8:00) for Jon considering the fact that dates are in diffrent years

Is the query good, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Strongly suggest not using regular integers for your time field. Use a field of type Time to denote what you need instead. Much more robust.

Comment: thank yo! im just testing the concept and will definitely change the field types later

Comment: @mason the original query of the asker already used `GROUP BY`, albeit the mistake was that the query grouped by `id` and then `fingerprint` (which equals to `id`), so it grouped by each record rather than only by `[full name]` and `date`. I have edited the question by a transcript of Rawad's initial query and written an answer that describes the ideas I have written here in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is almost correct, the mistake is that the `group by` clause in your query groups by `id` and then `fingerprint` and groups further by `[full name]` and then by `date`. Instead, you need to group only by `[full name]` and `date`:

```
select [full name], 
MIN(
    CASE
        WHEN state = 255 and fingerprint = id THEN time
        ELSE 999999
    END
) checkin,
MAX(
    CASE
        WHEN state = 1 and fingerprint = id THEN time
        ELSE -1
    END
) checkout,
cast (date as date)
FROM employee full outer join attendance on fingerprint = id
group by [full name],date
```

Comment: hello Lajos
thank you for your kind reply
i tried your suggestion and it gave an error 

Column 'employee.fingerprint' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

when i tried and added fingerprint to the group by it gave similar min and max values across all multiple dates 

a

Comment: @Rawad yup, it's an oversight on my part. I'll edit my answer shortly.

Comment: @Rawad updated my answer. Note that `MIN` and `MAX` are wrapped around the `case`-`when` conditionals and we default a large value (999999) for `checkin` and a small value (-1) for `checkout`.